# Why does the Numpy Diag function behaves weird?

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal

The *diag* function does not save the result to a variable.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(4,4)
d = np.diag(A)

print d
# above gives the diagonal entries of A

# let us change one entry
A[0, 0] = 0

print d
# above gives updated diagonal entries of A
```

Why does the *diag* function behave in this fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`np.diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) returns a *view* to the original array. This means later changes to the original array are reflected in the view. (The upside, however, is that the operation is in much faster than creating a copy.)

Note this is only the behavior in some versions of numpy. In others, a copy is returned.

To "freeze" the result, you can copy it like `d = np.diag(A).copy()`